# how to create and use own c++ functions instead of library built in ones

Tags: c#, c++

I have a csharp code which defines two functions Splice and FindIf for lists (already available in C++ for lists). I am trying create both functions for c++ to use without c++ built-in functions. Both csharp and c++ functions are given below

```
static class ListExtensions
{

    public static void Splice<T>(this List<T> list, int insertAtIndex, List<T> items,
        int first, int last)
    {
        if (items == null) return;
        insertAtIndex = Math.Min(list.Count, Math.Max(0, insertAtIndex));
        first = Math.Min(items.Count - 1, Math.Max(0, first));
        last = Math.Min(items.Count, Math.Max(1, last));
        if (first >= last) return;

        list.InsertRange(insertAtIndex, items.GetRange(first, last - first));
        items.RemoveRange(first, last - first);
    }

    public static int FindIf<T>(this List<T> list, int start, int end, Func<T, bool> method)
    {
        if (method == null) return end;
        if (!list.Any(method)) return end;
        start = Math.Min(list.Count - 1, Math.Max(0, start));
        end = Math.Min(list.Count, Math.Max(1, end));
        if (start >= end) return end;

        List<T> range = list.GetRange(start, end - start);
        int index = range.IndexOf(list.First(method));
        if (index < start) return end;
        return index;
    }
}
```

Csharp functions are called like below

```
static bool Move_tokens_to_statement(List<Evl_token> statementTokens, List<Evl_token> tokens)
    {
        Debug.Assert(tokens != null);

        int next_sc = tokens.FindIf(0, tokens.Count, TokenIsSemicolon);

        if (next_sc == tokens.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Looked for ';' but reached the end of the file.");
            return false;
        }

        ++next_sc;
        statementTokens.Splice(0, tokens, 0, next_sc);
        return true;
    }
```

C++ code I have written to date is given below

```
template<typename T>
void Splice(std::list<T> &List, int insertAtIndex, std::list<T> items,
int first, int last)
{
    if (items == null) return;
    insertAtIndex = std::min(List.size(), (int)std::max(0, insertAtIndex));
    first = std::min(items.size() - 1, std::max(0, first));
    last = std::min(items.size(), std::max(1, last));
    if (first >= last) return;
    std::copy(first, last-first, std::back_inserter(items));
    List.insert(insertAtIndex, items);
    items.erase(first, last - first);
};

template<typename T>
int FindIf(std::list<T> &List, int start, int end, bool(*method)(T))
{
    if (method == null) return end;
    if (!(std::any_of(List.begin(),List.end(),return method))) return end;
    start = std::min(List.size() - 1, std::max(0, start));;
    end = std::min(List.size(), std::max(1, end));
    if (start >= end) return end;
    list<T> range = std::copy(start, end - start, std::back_inserter(List));    
    int index = range.IndexOf(List.Front(method));
    if (index < start) return end;
    return index;
};
```

Errors which I see for both c++ defined Splice and FindIf functions are as below

FindIf called on list has error "no instance of FindIf matches the argument list. argument types are ...."

Splice called on list has error "Class std::list .... has no member Splice"

What is best way to define own functions for my code in c++ and what will be solution?

Comment: Show us the  calls as well as the definitions please.

Comment: Note that C++ (currently) does not have the equivalent of extension functions.  You have to call as `FindIf(mylist, 1, 3, mypredicate)`

Comment: I think there are some other errors  too: for ex. in int index = range.IndexOf(list.Front(method));  the variable name should be probably List and not list.

Comment: @MartinBonner yes I am calling like you said which shows error mentioned

Comment: @StPiere edited and corrected that

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 primary ways.

The traditional way is to call your functions (like you have defined them) like nonmember functions.

The avant-garde way introduced by boost is to overload an operator such as `|` for syntax such as `myList | FindIf(...) | Unique() | Reversed()`. You can see how this was done in the [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/introduction.html) library.